# PyCharm: Using SIFT with opencv-contrib (Mac)

Tags: macos, opencv, pycharm, opencv-contrib

I have a Python/OpenCV project and I am trying to use the xfeatures2d module from opencv-contrib.  I am using a Mac and my IDE is PyCharm. I have installed the packages opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python through Preferences > Project Intepreter.

However, when I try to run the code below, I get a the following error:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("NotreDame.jpg", 0)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()


line 6, in <module>
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1207: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) This algorithm is patented and is excluded in this configuration; Set OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE CMake option and rebuild the library in function 'create'
```

I have installed opencv and opencv-contrib on my computer using:

```
 $ pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.17
 $ pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

I am not sure how I can resolve this error. Any insights are appreciated.